# UIAlertController doesn't shown for iOS app on macOS

Tags: ios, macos, apple-silicon

I have an iOS app that when run on macOS will present an alert in response to a user action.

```swift
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Choose an action", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { _ in
    // ...
})
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Action 1", style: .default, handler: { _ in
    // ...
}))
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Action 2", style: .default, handler: { _ in
    // ...
}))

present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This crashes with the error:

> Your application has presented a UIAlertController (<UIAlertController: 0x135010400>) of style UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet from ExampleViewController (<ExampleViewController: 0x133826c00>). The modalPresentationStyle of a UIAlertController with this style is UIModalPresentationPopover. You must provide location information for this popover through the alert controller's popoverPresentationController. You must provide either a sourceView and sourceRect or a barButtonItem.  If this information is not known when you present the alert controller, you may provide it in the UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate method -prepareForPopoverPresentation.

When running on iOS or iPadOS setting the properties on the `popoverPresentationController` is not required because this is using the `actionSheet` style. This view controller does not have access to a `UIBarButtonItem` so setting the `barButtonItem` property isn't an option. If I do set the `sourceView` and `sourceRect` properties (as shown below) it instead logs autolayout errors and no alert is shown:

```swift
if #available(iOS 14.0, *), ProcessInfo.processInfo.isiOSAppOnMac {
    alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = view
    alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = view.bounds
}
```

```
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x600003a1a3a0 h=--& v=--& UIView:0x12914af30.height == 13   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003a1f750 UIView:0x129067d90.height >= 44   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003a1fed0 _UIAlertControllerView:0x1290677a0'Choose an action'.height == UIView:0x129067d90.height   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003a19040 UIView:0x12914af30.height == _UIAlertControllerView:0x1290677a0'Choose an action'.height   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003a1f750 UIView:0x129067d90.height >= 44   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.

[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x600003a1a350 h=--& v=--& UIView:0x12914af30.width == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003a4e0d0 UIView:0x129067d90.width == 270   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003a1fe80 _UIAlertControllerView:0x1290677a0'Choose an action'.width >= UIView:0x129067d90.width   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003a18ff0 UIView:0x12914af30.width == _UIAlertControllerView:0x1290677a0'Choose an action'.width   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003a4e0d0 UIView:0x129067d90.width == 270   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

How can I use `UIAlertController` in an iOS app running on macOS? Please note: this *not* a Catalyst app, this is an iOS app running natively on an Apple Silicon Mac.

Comment: Apple suggests using the alert style on macOS, as opposed to action sheets which aren’t really a thing on macOS.

Comment: That being said my action sheets have worked without issue once I provided a source view and rect, at least in testing on Ventura.